# Java linked list implementation

Tags: java, linked-list, implementation, singly-linked-list

I am learning Linked Lists right now and I'm a little confused.  I'm working on an assignment where we're creating our own implementation of some methods to be used with a linked list.

I watched a lot of videos on the concept of Linked List and how Nodes work like getting data and setting the next element but I'm confused on how to make a list to test the methods I'm implementing.  I know this may sound silly but I start to get super confused with multiple parameters in methods and return statements get involved and I've never worked with a generic data type before either so those basic ideas might be confusing me here.

**I'd love some help with creating a list so I can test the methods as I'm creating them, I'm having difficulty printing out a list.  I get that what I'm doing in the main is creating new nodes and adding to some list but I honestly don't know where this supposed LinkedList is or what it's called.  Any help is greatly appreciated!!  FYI, I'm very new to Java, this is my second class and it's online and not a very well constructed class, please be nice lol**

I get the concept of this BUT what is the name of the list (or linked list) these are being added to?

```
    ListNode node4 = new ListNode("Fourth", null);
    ListNode node3 = new ListNode("Third", node4);
    ListNode node2 = new ListNode("Second", node3);
    ListNode node1 = new ListNode("First", node2);
```

I DON'T KNOW HOW I CAN PRINT THESE OUT INDIVIDUALLY LIKE I CAN WITH THE ABOVE BECAUSE I CAN USE THE NAMES ABOVE

```
ListNode value = new ListNode("First", new ListNode("Second", new ListNode("Third", null) ));
```

Here is my code with the testing class where I have questions as comments which may help you understand what I'm confused about if I'm not making sense above.  I left out the ListNode class as it is your basic getNext() setNext() Node class called ListNode with a generic type ....

```
//Testing program for SinglyLinkedList class
public class LinkedListDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();                   //comment out this line to test your code
    SinglyLinkedList<String> list = new SinglyLinkedList<String>();  //remove comment to test your code
    SinglyLinkedList SLL = new SinglyLinkedList();

    ListNode node4 = new ListNode("Fourth", null);
    ListNode node3 = new ListNode("Third", node4);
    ListNode node2 = new ListNode("Second", node3);
    ListNode node1 = new ListNode("First", node2);

//ListNode value = new ListNode("First", new ListNode("Second", new ListNode("Third", null) ));

System.out.println(node2.getData());

//Is this the correct way to add a new node to this method?
    SLL.addLast(new ListNode("Fifth", null));
//I doubt my printList is correct as I do not know what parameter I am       supposed to pass to it.    
    SLL.printList();
}
```

SinglyLinkedList class

```
//This class implements a very simple singly-linked list of Objects
public class SinglyLinkedList<E> {
     ListNode<E> first; // first element

public SinglyLinkedList()  {
    first = null;
}

public E getFirst() {
   if (first == null) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
   }
   else
      return first.getData();
   }

public void addFirst(E value) {
    first = new ListNode<E>(value, first);
}

// Methods below implemented by you. Note: while writing methods, keep in mind
// that you might be able to call other methods in this class to help you - you
// don't always need to start from scratch(but you'll have to recognize when)
public void addLast(E value) {    
    ListNode<E> temp = first;
    //If list is empty make new node the first node.
    if(temp == null) {
        first = new ListNode <E>(value, null);
        first.setNext(null);
    }
    //Otherwise loop to end of list and add new node.
    else {
        while(temp.getNext() != null) {
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
    temp.setNext(new ListNode<E>(value, null));
    }
}//end addLast

// throws an exception - you decide when and which one
public E getLast() {
    ListNode<E> temp = first;
    if(temp == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("There are no elements in this list to get.");
    }
    else {
        while(temp.getNext() != null) {
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        return temp.getData();
    }
}

// throws an exception - you decide when and which one
public E removeFirst() {
    if(first == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("There are no elements in this list to remove.");
    }
    ListNode<E> tempRemove = first;  
    return null;//just so it'll compile
  }

  // throws an exception - you decide when and which one
  public E removeLast() {
     return null; //just so it'll compile
  }

  // return the number of elements in the list
  public int size() {
      return 0;//just so it'll compile
  }

  // return true if o is in this list, otherwise false
  public boolean contains(E obj) {
      return true;//just so it'll compile
  }

 public void printList(java.io.PrintStream out) {
     if(first == null) {
        System.out.println("The list is empty");
     }
     ListNode<E> current = first;
     while(current != null) {
         System.out.println(current.toString());
         current = current.getNext();
     }
  }

  public String toString() {
       String s = "[";
       ListNode<E> current = first;
    //write code to traverse the list, adding each object on its own line
    while(current.getNext() != null) {
        current = current.getNext();
    }

  s += "]";
  return s;
  }

  // OPTIONAL: just for fun...and a challenge
  public void reverse() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your questions outside the code ? Can't read them and very difficult to find them.

Comment: My questions in Bold but I'll take those comments out and add them with that part outside the code too as to be less confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linked lists are basic data structures.

A basic linked list implementation is as follows:

```
class LinkedListNode {
  int value;
  LinkedListNode next;
}
```

The basic idea is that you can iterate through the list by checking to see if the list has a `next` parameter, like so: `while (currentNode.next != null) { ... }`.

Printing out the values of a linked list takes advantage of the aforementioned while-loop, and you just print the value of the current node.

You can think of a linked list as a line of people who can only see the person ahead of them, and not who is behind them. You know where the person at the very start of the line -- that is, the one with nobody 'behind' him -- is. This person is called the "head" of the list. He knows who is directly in front of him, and each person knows who is directly in front of him. When you reach the point where somebody doesn't have anyone in front of them, you've gone through the whole line.

Here's an example of adding a new element to the end of a list:

```
LinkedListNode node = myListHead;
while (node.next != null) {
  node = node.next;
}
node.next = new LinkedListNode(...);
```

Comment: I totally get that, I get the concept of how it works I'm just confused on this assignment....In my main the nodes I'm creating, what "Linked List" are those being added too?  How do I test my methods as I write them?  I want to just have a basic list that I can then pass into the methods I'm writing and test them as I go...Am I making any sense?  lol

Comment: Yeah I get that, I watched some videos where the guy did a really job idea of explaining the concept and how to draw them out...Does that mean they're different then like an Array or ArrayLists where you have an ArrayList called namesArrayList and you can add items to it, a LinkedList are individual nodes Linked together but don't have an actual name for the "Linked List" as a whole?

Comment: In an ArrayList, you have an array that "grows" as needed, as you add more things to it. Because of that, you can access an element by its index. In a standard singly-linked list, you don't have access to nodes in the middle or end of a list -- you only have direct access to the root. Because of this, you must iterate through the list to find the value that you're looking for. In order to add a new value to the end of the list, you must iterate to the end and add a value at the end. I'll edit my post and include an example of this.

Comment: Right now my printList() method is only printing out what I'm assuming is some kind of memory address (ListNode@7852e922)

Comment: @sjud9227 you can't just print out the object. You must print out the object's value: `System.out.println(node.value);`

Comment: So the only thing you're essentially naming is the variable that you set that points to the first node?  In my code above I create a node LsitNode node3 = new ListNode("Third", node4); I understand what it's doing but I can use those names to print out the value for those individual nodes

Comment: In general, you should only have access to the head of the list.

Comment: Oh I should be using getData instead of getNext right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93269/discussion-between-wadda-wadda-and-sjud9227).